# how can I minimize requests of direction api?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, mobile, google-maps

We are updating polyline on each update of driver's location by requesting on direction API during ride session. In a minute 10 requests are generating which is too much costly for me by business point of view. I have searched a lot, also contact to google support but found nothing. I'm stuck on it from 5 days.

Comment: Call the API fewer times? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or a description of how you've architected the API calls there is very little anyone can help you with.

Comment: Yea Sir I'm calling direction API when driver change is location. Driver's location is feting on Realtime. On each update of location of driver. API is beaning called. Is there anyther way?? to update route without hitting direction API?

Comment: "update route without hitting direction API" = update location without getting the location. See how that sounds?

Comment: Sir driver's location is updating 10 times in a minute. So if after 100 minutes it will become 1000. and this type of ride expect near to 5$ but here my google play account will charge me 5$ also. So its not applicable for business point of view. I wana reduce these requests of direction API.